# How to assign a bean message to a jsp parameter

Tags: jsp, message, param, jspinclude

How can I assign a bean message, for example: `<bean:message key="leftmenu.dailyreport"/>`
to a `JSP` parameter? I tried:

```
<jsp:include page="/pages/common/common006-tabmenu.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="upperMenu1" value=<bean:message key="leftmenu.dailyreport"/> >
    </jsp:param>        
</jsp:include>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,in my case by using bean message will show the message "Enter the email" , that is assigned in email property and next to it , it will take input value of email from user.

```
     <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" align="center" width="100%">
     <tr>
        <td class="back" width="38%"><bean:message                    key="createUser.email"/></td>
          <td class="tableback" width="62%">
            <html:text property="email" value='<%=email%>'       readonly="true" onkeydown="return false;" onfocus = "return false;" onkeypress="return false;"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
```